# What are the settings for emailing a member through CP?

Tags: members, control-panel, zoo-visitor, permissions

I have a membergroup "Admins" and 3 other member groups.
I want to give the admins the ability to email a member via the CP.

I'm using ZooVistor here (zoovistior fieldtype)

But I keep getting the following message when I click 'Email member'

> An Error Was Encountered You are not authorized to access this page

I enabled the following settings already:

- Can access TOOLS: Communication
- Can send email via the ControlPanel
- Can send email to Member Groups
- Can send email to Mailing List
- Can view/send cached email
- Can administrate members accounts

I'm using EE v2.5.3 - Build Date: 20120911

Thanks

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the 'Email member' link you mention in your question. I'm trying to understand where in the CP this link lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding "Can access TOOLS section" to the permissions for the member group.

Comment: yes indeed, simple, but too simple to miss it? :-)

Comment: This is an issue with the EE permissions that isn't documented at all... maybe it's a bug?

Comment: It's rather a hierarchical issue I think, if I enable "can access Tools: Communication", it's rather logic I also want to enable "Can access Tools Section"

Comment: I couldn't agree more. If you feel up to it, you might consider reporting as a bug so they can make the adjustments in core code. This top level permission should be a given when selecting secondary levels.